# Mathematical Induction question Using $n\ge t\ge 0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

> 5. Let $n\geq t\geq 0$. Show that $$\sum_{j=t}^{n}\binom{j}{t}=\binom{n+1}{t+1}$$
>      I am stuck on this question. The fact thats it is multivariable is confusing me.

Comment: Don't worry about $t$. Just show it is true  with $n=t$ and then show if true for $n$ then it is true for $n+1$.

Comment: You’ll find several different proofs at the earlier question, including algebraic and combinatorial proofs and a proof by induction.